# HTML text display Limit for table column

Tags: html, css

I have a table which width of it is 200px.

it has 2 columns:

1. Title (simple text, link,...)
2. Logo (img)

**issue is**: when Title + Logo exceed 200px I need to limit only **Title**.

```
------------------------
|Title      |Logo      |
------------------------
|Helloooo...|img       |
------------------------
```

**Constraints** only HTML and CSS

I try different thinks:

```
overflow: hidden; 
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
white-space: nowrap;
table-layout:fixed;
...
```

only result which I'm getting is:

```
------------------------
|Title      |Logo      |
------------------------
|Helloooooooooooo|img       | -> more than 200px
------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/*Write CSS Code as Below*/

.appadd {

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
width: 180px;
height: 30px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

}

[Live Demo - Goto this Link](http://jsfiddle.net/chathuramadhusanka/aNHa6/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **CSS** `word-wrap` to split those words that are extremely large:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/ySJGC/) Example!

```
.title {
    width: 100px;            /* adjust the value to fit your needs */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Note:**

- Since the word-wrap needs some block level element, you need at least
  to set the `TD` with `display:inline-block`.
- Since the `word-wrap` breaks the word when she's overflowing the
  wrapper, you need to give a fixed width to the `TD`.

---

You can check the Browser compatibility table [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap#AutoCompatibilityTable).

Comment: Should work just fine, can you present the relevant HTML markup along with the relevant CSS to simulate that issue on a Fiddle ?

Comment: @SairuS, updated the answer with a working solution and a Fiddle to confirm it.

Comment: As we are forcing first column to be 100px, and in case when img is just 24px then no need to limit/wrap the title to 100

Comment: @SairuS, that is just a matter of adjusting the width value, see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/ySJGC/1/)!

Comment: @SairuS, See the second note where I point out that the word-wrap needs the be working with a fixed width on the wrapper element in order to break the word! If no width specified, the browser does not have a reason to break the word.

Comment: agree that word-wrap needs the be working with a fixed width, but I don't know on build time what is the width. Looks like Rafael was right, CSS will not be able to solve this issue & JavaScript till be required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not posible with HTML and CSS, if you want to do it in the client side you may use javascript, getting the width of the Title cell, and then trimming the text accordingly, for this you can use the [Substring function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), althrought you may want to use a JavaScript library like jQuery

Comment: I din't find any CSS solution and as result was forced to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

CSS solutions worked for me to some degree but not consistently across browsers.  So, I picked up on Rafael's suggestion and used Substring.  In my case, Html.Raw is not a risk.  This is my code - probably not very elegant but works well:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            var exploreText = item.ExploreText;
            var exploreTextShort = "";
            if (exploreText != null)
            {
                if (exploreText.ToString().Length > 15)
                {
                    exploreTextShort = exploreText.ToString().Substring(0, 15);
                }
                else { exploreTextShort = exploreText; }
            }
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Raw(exploreTextShort)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```