# Select element comes clear after getting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table which has "Mortgage Type" column as an editable field where the user can select a value in the dropdown and enter some text in the input field available. 
Default value shown in the Mortgage Type dropdown list is "Auto". When the user enters some data in any rows (ex.,1st row, and 4th row) and clicks on the submit button, I'm clearing the fields and displaying the data which I got from backend. It works as expected.

**Issue** I'm facing is when user click on *GetData* button. I'm clearing the input  entered by user and showing the data which I got from the backend, but **it is clearing 
the default value, shown in the Mortgage Type dropdown, which should be "Auto"** for all the fields except for the values which I got from the database(**var mortageType** - shown in the first two rows of the table..)

```
  $('.mortgageType').val(''); //clearing all the dropdown values and showing blank as the code suggests..
```

**Another issue** is `word-wrap: break-word;` is not working for the columns. I don't want to extend the column size when the value is long, instead, I want to do `word-wrap: break-word;`. But in my code when the user clicks on the GetData button, the value in the Status field for the first row is long and it is extending the column.
I tried to use the below CSS in the style attribute which is not working.

```
<div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status2" style="word-wrap: break-word;"></div>
```

Demo code (also on [Plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co/edit/ejftJHE3jlZrGMRs54kf?p=preview)):

```js
function submitData() {
  var flag = true;
  $('#loanTable input[type="text"]').val('');
  $('.mortgageType').val(''); //to clear the dropdown value
  $('.order').val('');
  var enablingFlag = true;
  if (flag) {
    //values from backend
    var mortageType = [{
      "code": "Home",
      "description": "Home"
    }, {
      "code": "Car",
      "description": "Car"
    }];
    var loanNum = [{
      "code": "23432",
      "description": "23432"
    }, {
      "code": "12123",
      "description": "12123"
    }];
    var status = [{
      "code": "Approved",
      "description": "Approved"
    }, {
      "code": "Pending, need more documents",
      "description": "Pending, need more documents"
    }];
    var j = 0;
    //iterate and show the jsonData in the table2 when user click on submit button
    for (var i = 0; i < mortageType.length; i++) {
      j = j + 1;
      document.getElementById("mortageType" + j).value = mortageType[i].code;
      document.getElementById("loanNum" + j).innerText = loanNum[i].code;
      document.getElementById("status" + j).innerText = status[i].code;
      if (loanNum[i].code == null || mortageType[i].code == null || status[i].code == null) {
        console.log("row has null value");
        $('#status' + j).parent().parent().css({
          'border': 'red'
        });
      }

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="loanTable" id="loanTable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> <label for="show"><span name="3765" maxlength="1"class="message">Year</span></label> </th>
      <th> <label for="show"><span name="568" maxlength="1" class="message">Mortgage Type</span>&nbsp;
            <span name="496" maxlength="1" class="message"></span>
        </label>
      </th>
      <th> <label for="show"><span name="3702" maxlength="1" class="message">Loan Num</span></label> </th>
      <th> <label for="show"><span name="2366" maxlength="1" class="message">Status</span></label> </th>
      <th> <label for="show"><span name="179"  maxlength="1" class="message">Comments</span></label> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
        <select id="year" name="year" disabled>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField">
          <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
          <select id="mortageType1" name="mortageType1" class="mortgageType">
            <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
            <option value="Home">Home</option>
            <option value="Car">Car</option>
          </select>
          <input name="ord1" id="ord1" class="order">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="loanNum1"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status1" style="word-wrap: break-word;"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="comments1"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!--Second row-->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
        <select id="year" name="year" disabled>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField">
          <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
          <select id="mortageType2" name="mortageType2" class="mortgageType">
            <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
            <option value="Home">Home</option>
            <option value="Car">Car</option>
          </select>
          <input name="ord2" id="ord2" class="order">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="loanNum2"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status2" style="word-wrap: break-word;"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="comments2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!--Third Row-->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
        <select id="year" name="year" disabled>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField">
          <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
          <select id="mortageType3" name="mortageType3" class="mortgageType">
            <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
            <option value="Home">Home</option>
            <option value="Car">Car</option>
          </select>
          <input name="ord3" id="ord3" class="order">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="loanNum3"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status3" style="word-wrap: break-word;"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="comments3"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--Fourth Row-->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
        <select id="year" name="year" disabled>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField">
          <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
          <select id="mortageType3" name="mortageType4" class="mortgageType">
            <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
            <option value="Home">Home</option>
            <option value="Car">Car</option>
          </select>
          <input name="ord4" id="ord4" class="order">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="loanNum4"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status4"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="comments4"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!--Fifth Row-->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
        <select id="year" name="year" disabled>
          <option value="2018">2018</option>
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField">
          <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label>
          <select id="mortageType3" name="mortageType5" class="mortgageType">
            <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
            <option value="Home">Home</option>
            <option value="Car">Car</option>
          </select>
          <input name="ord5" id="ord5" class="order">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="loanNum5"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status5"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cloneX10 indField" id="comments5"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table><br>
<input type="submit" value="GetData" onclick="submitData()">
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of clearing that, set it as "Auto" default 
   replace `$('.mortgageType').val('');` with `$('.mortgageType').val('Auto');`
2. You can use `style="max-width:100px;"` for those `th` tags

Comment: Hi - Welcome to Stack Overflow - could you add some details to your answer as to why this works?

Comment: @Ciu Alex - Thanks for the inputs. I don't want to give the width specifically for each columns..So i can't use style="max-width:100px;".

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to clear value of all select elements. So a simple solution is comment this line of code:

JS:

```
//$('.mortgageType').val('');
// or something simple like line below
$('.mortgageType').val('Auto'); //So you'll set "Auto" to all selet elements and in the loop you'll change them based on what database returns.
```

And to preventing extending column you have a solution like below:

HTML/CSS:

```
<table class="loanTable" id="loanTable" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    ...
    <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status2" style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;"></div></td>
```

Or you can use `overflow-x: scroll;` instead of `overflow: hidden;` to have a scrollbar to reading extended content. Check this link out: [Plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co/edit/NAQVLGGi4LW3corZbgl0?p=preview)

**P.S.** If you have any further questions, or you think this is not your answer just let me in comment sections down below.

---

Another solution for preventing columns to be extended, answered in this thread:
[Display limit for table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954188/html-text-display-limit-for-table-column/20591710)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I tried with the code you shared, it is not working. When user click on GetData it is still expanding the status column when the text is long. Demo https://plnkr.co/edit/41wuZ1oq0fQfGeUvwW1w?p=preview

Comment: @user3684675 You checked my demo? https://plnkr.co/edit/NAQVLGGi4LW3corZbgl0?p=preview

Comment: Yes, i tried your demo, even the plunker you shared https://plnkr.co/edit/NAQVLGGi4LW3corZbgl0?p=preview is extending the status column width when user clicked on GetData to fit the values Approved and Pending, need more documents values in the Status column. Thanks.

Comment: @user3684675 I am afraid you can't figure out this is your answer because of lacking your knowledge about codes. I showed you (in 2-3 ways) how to preventing table column to be expanded. In my demo i used flexible, one line method, if its not look like what you looking for, use `overflow` that i said afterward and if it's not what you want either, use the link that i provided beneath that.

Comment: Yes, Auto thing is resolved. I'm sorry i have checked your code again, it is not working with any options.It is extending the column width. I tried with overflow-x: scroll; and with overflow: hidden; . I dont want to show ellipsis so have not tried the sample shown in the link you shared. Sorry to ask same thing so many times but it is not working.

Comment: @user3684675 I made some changes, maybe this is what you want. Check this link and thanks for fast reply https://plnkr.co/edit/NAQVLGGi4LW3corZbgl0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks it worked, only thing is i don't want to show the scrollbar so removed css white-space: nowrap and other question is, is it mandatory to give the width?I will accept the answer soon. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @user3684675 Unfortunately yes, i know its not your goal to have limited/static width, but without width table will expand to its content.